# how do you develop "create site" workflow in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

i want to try doing this directly in SP2010 designer first.  I have never worked with workflow before and haven't found anything that really helped me out online.

Flow:
I go into a global team site.  I fill out a form (predefined form i created with specific controls) and click submit (form is validated for input).
Workflow kicks starts sending an email to a user who is defined to approve this workflow.
Once approval is obtained, the workflow completes and creates a Team Site from the information in the initial Form I filled out.

I am sure this is simple for anyone who has been developing workflows, but again this is my first and my first time using SP2010.

Any help starting this would greatly be appreciated.  I haven't really found any good examples online for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just completed a project exactly like this. We made a list with all the fields necessary to create a site. We attached a custom Approval workflow created in SharePoint Designer and a Workflow Event Receiver. When the Approval workflow finished, the [WorkflowCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventreceiver.workflowcompleted.aspx) event checked that the workflow outcome was Approved, retrieved the List Item associated to the Task, and passed that List Item to our builder class.

Comment: sounds exactly like what i need to do.  thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes. Create a SharePoint 2010 project in Visual Studio 2010. Select Add New Item and select the Event Receiver template. Once the Event Receiver is built, you can create a Feature and add the Event Receiver to the Feature.